# Get link parsing html and start parsing another html

Tags: python, lxml

I use lxml library Python 3 for parsing html document. I can get some link from it using entree.xpath. But is there any way to get some data from  html which corresponds to linked website ?

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you just want to get the HTML of some website?

Comment: Yes, there likely is. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: to get HTML from server use standard module `urllib.request` or external (but very popular)  module `requests` - ie. `html = requests.get(url).text`